# What font and style of this document is?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone has a way to produced something alike the following,
I saw this first [here](https://tslil.xyz/store/cats.pdf).

[image]

and the titles have this presentation (like centered):

[image]

Comment: I'd say kpfonts

Comment: If you have the pdf simply list the fonts in the font menu of your pdf viewer.

Comment: The font looks like `kpfonts`